# Use pen to drag slider bar

Tags: sculpt

is there a set up where I can use my pen to drag a slider such as brush radius?

When I click on the slider I have to enter values and I would prefer to use the pen to slide the value. I know I can use <kbd>f</kbd> but would like to make use of the slider. thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use your pen with a fast click on a slider you can enter a value, but if you put (with the pen) your cursor on the slider and slide, the slider acts as .... a slider! (At least, this is what happens with my Wacom Intuos on 2.8 in sculpt mode).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I right click (using the pen) to bring up the dialogue box. I hover the cursor over the slider and as soon as I touch the slider it immediately wants a value rather than sliding. Must be missing something here -thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Input > Tablet API > Switch to Windows Ink*

Answer (score -1):

Adding to "Go to Edit > Preferences > Input > Tablet API > Switch to Windows Ink"

Your Wacom Tablet itself also has the option to use windows ink itself, you might want to check that.[image]